# Re-execution of directives inside ng-repeat directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following setup:

```
            <div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="(professorKey, oProfessor) in JsonTeachers">
                <div class="dropzone box teacher-chart">
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 title">
                        <h2>{{oProfessor.id_professor}}</h2>
                    </div>
                    <h3>DROPZONE</h3>
                    <app-graph align="center">
                    </app-graph>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The code executes right the first time.
The problem here comes when we change the value of JsonTeachers (we add a new object/teacher). In this case the ng-repeat will execute again however the directive "" wont.

Main problem idea is: Re-execution of directives inside ng-repeat directive

In case is needed here is the code of the directive (it just paints a graph).However it never gets to be executed (again)

```
return { 
    restrict: 'E', 
    scope: { 
    professor: '=',
    },
    controller: 'mainController',
    templateUrl: '/js/directives/appGraph.html',
    link: function (scope, element) {
       scope.oMaestros=jsonConversion.getJsonGraph();
       scope.Arrayprof=[];
       for ( var professor in scope.oMaestros){
           var graph = {};
           graph = scope.comunOptions;
           graph.chart.renderTo = professor + "_id";
           graph.yAxis.title = professor;
           graph.series = scope.oMaestros[professor].series.slice(0);

           eval('scope. ' + professor + '_id =new Highcharts.chart(professor + "_id",graph);')
           scope.Arrayprof[i]=professor;
           delete graph;
       }// end for
    }
}//end return
```

Comment: Post directives code, that may help to suggest a solution

Comment: I don't think the problem is in what contains the directive since it never gets to execute it (I've tested it)

Comment: you can watch `professor` which you have a two way binding on it. And re-execute a function which creates the graph

Comment: I will do that thanks